# Python and Json - Best way to pull out sections of data from API?

Tags: python, json, api, post

Want to figure out the best way to grab and organize the parts I want from the API since it displays large amounts of useless data.

Input

```
response = requests.get('https://urlscan.io/api/v1/result/' + uuid + '/')
r3 = response.content.decode("utf-8")
print(r3)
```

Output: (https://urlscan.io/api/v1/result/1742c69a-17eb-4089-a01e-18decd64579c)

```
*Only displaying bottom of data*
    "hashes": [
      "c67d9981ef9235ddcc3081be2c92f402b7525e5601970eb4811a3ea941d82448",
      "60b19e5da6a9234ff9220668a5ec1125c157a268513256188ee80f2d2c8d8d36",
      "970c15466fc742d78103ec93f9d78741ae743c6d08fbaec2fb0f541897b53f97",
      "5407e68f9bd5a647a464ebf80920fa1289747821da4497f020ede6c843701178",
      "3990ce6ae2ec606267ea6bee16b21dbd9bf5847dddb6e3f51c3539765c8a5af9",
    ]
  },
  "verdicts": {
    "overall": {
      "score": 0,
      "categories": [],
      "brands": [],
      "tags": [],
      "malicious": false,
      "hasVerdicts": 0
    },
    "urlscan": {
      "score": 0,
      "categories": [],
      "brands": [],
      "tags": [],
      "detectionDetails": [],
      "malicious": false
    },
    "engines": {
      "score": 0,
      "malicious": [],
      "benign": [],
      "maliciousTotal": 0,
      "benignTotal": 0,
      "verdicts": [],
      "enginesTotal": 0
    },
}
```

There's a lot of data I want but, also a lot of useless data. Whats the best way to do something along the lines of

```
Hashes:
*hash 1*
*hash 2*
*hash 3...*

Verdict:
Score: 0
Malicious: False

(next part I want, etc, etc)
```

So I don't grab the entirety of the section that only has parts of what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer above is great but I also got an extra solution to this

```py
import requests
import json

req = requests.Session()

r = req.get("API Link").json()
#instead of json.loads, I used .json() to make it a bit more simple
```

Answer (score 1):

Just import the `json` library and use the `loads` method. It should be something like this:

```
import requests 
import json

response = requests.get(URL)
data = json.loads(response.text)
```

then you can navigate the data as a normal python dictionary. To get the keys use `data.keys()` and then access the data with `data[key]`.